# ConcurrentLinkedDeque lock-free alternative in Java 1.6

Tags: java, multithreading, list, data-structures, lock-free

Is there a data structure in 1.6 that is lock-free and thread-safe while I can access elements in both directions? While 1.6 has [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and implements the [fast non-blocking algorithm](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf), any 3rd party data structure that gives similar functionality?

Comment: There is a ConcurrentLinkedDeque in Java 7 - you may be able to copy paste the code and use that.

Comment: The comment to which I replied is deleted. It said `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` exists in 1.6

Comment: @assylias I can't do it. I get unsafe security exception. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This is how to hack the Unsafe security check...: http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-sunmiscunsafe